# Is mysql.connector supported in Python Anywhere?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Im new to pythonanywhere yet I have made my webapp run on their server. My website domain is http://knowfahad.pythonanywhere.com/.

The problem is that I used mysql.connector for database stuff and whenever the databse is being accessed on the website, the error 500 is shown.

My question is whether mysql.connector is supported by python anywhere?

Comment: 500 internal server error. Post some logs, then we'll tell you if it's unsupported

Answer (score 3):

Yes MySQL is supported. If python 2.x, you need to use `import MySQLdb`

And if you're using MySQL with Python 3, you need to install a module. If you're not using a virtualenv, run:

```
$ pip3.4 install --user mysqlclient
```

https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingMySQL/

Comment: Code from python file :
  import mysql.connector
This is different from import MySQLdb right?

Comment: They are different, yes

Comment: I'm using mysql.connector. Now I know why the database error is arising. Thanks. I'll edit the code for Mysqldb library.

Comment: Assuming you have access to install whatever you want via pip, use whatever you are comfortable with.